# White light Hawking radiation

Tags: black-holes, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation

If the Hawking radiation is similar in spectrum to a black body, then at what mass of the black hole its radiation would have the same peak energy as the sunlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent temperature of a black hole (as seen from infinity- since the blackbody radiation will be red-shifted as it moves away from the black hole) is given by $$\frac{1}{8\pi M}$$ in natural units. Or with all the constants in there: $$\frac{\hbar c^3}{8\pi k_BGM}$$

For the Sun's temperature of $5778\rm K$, this corresponds to $2\cdot 10^{19} \rm kg$. Or about 3 millionths the mass of the earth. Impossibly small for a black hole, of course.

Edit: requested in comment

The Schwarzschild radius for the black hole would be $31\rm nm$. Since it's blackbody radiation, the power should be determined by the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), so the luminosity is given by: $$ L = 4\pi r^2 \sigma T^4$$

Plugging this in gives a total luminosity of around 800 nanowatts. So very tiny. To find out the lifetime, we can set up an differential equation: $$\frac{dM}{dt}=-\frac{L}{c^2}=-\frac{4\pi r^2\sigma T^4}{c^2}$$

Changing to natural units so this doesn't get super long (note that $\sigma=\frac{\pi^2}{60}$ in natural units) and substituting in $r$ and $T$: $$\frac{dM}{dt}=-\frac{\pi^3(2M)^2\left(\frac{1}{8\pi M}\right)^4}{15}=-\frac{1}{15360\pi M^2}$$

Rearranging this and integrating: $$\int_{M_0}^0M^2dM=-\int_0^t\frac{dt'}{15360\pi}$$

$$\frac{M^3}{3}=\frac{t}{15360}$$ $$t=5120M^3$$

Putting the constants back in: $$t=\frac{5120G^2M^3}{\hbar c^4}$$

For our initial numbers, this gives you $8\cdot 10^{33} \rm yr$. So it comes out to be an extremely dim light bulb that will be around for an unimaginably long time.

For fun: a black hole the mass of the Empire State building would last for thirty years and would start out with a luminosity of 3.2 *petawatts*, about 500 times the world's power usage, or 100 small nuclear bombs per second. And it would get *brighter* over the thirty year period.

Comment: Great, a tiny, yet heavy light bulb. While on it, could you also figure out the intensity? For example, is there such a distance, at which this BH would have to be to provide the Earth with the same energy as the Sun does? Say, we put it on an orbit around the Earth? Or would it be rather comparable in intensity to a street light? And finally, how long would it last? Just the ballpark :)

Comment: @safesphere Added to my answer. Did you one better than just the ballpark too ;)