# Are black hole event horizons hotter than our Sun?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, temperature, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

The outside (not inside) of black holes, the event horizon, are apparently extremely hot, and get even hotter the smaller in size and mass they are. Being completely black, are they generally more hotter than normal stars? Are black holes hotter than our sun?

An in-detail comparison of their heat and the heat of the sun would be appreciated, if not only temperature but electromagnetic radiation measurements.

Comment: *Black holes are apparently extremely hot.* What did you read or watch that made you think this?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation): A black hole of one solar mass has a temperature of only 60 nanokelvins.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the accretion disk getting hot? That's a very different thing, do you want to [edit] the question after you've done some rethinking?

Comment: Here is a hypothetical black hole as hot as our Sun: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362721/

Comment: Further to @Ghoster's comment, the temperature is inversely proportional to mass, so for a high temperature you'd need a  Kugelblitz or a small primordial black hole, not astronomical black holes.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. yeah the outside or accretion disk. To the others, of course not the inside.

Comment: Note that the Hawking temperature of $T≈60\,\mathrm{nK}\cdot M_\text{sun}/M$ applies to the event horizon, which is still reasonably the “outside” of the black hole. The accretion disk is a time-varying feature of the black hole’s environment. A sufficiently isolated black hole may consume its accretion disk and go dark; an accretion disk may grow brighter if new material is added to it.

Comment: ok, then event horizon is hot, not accretion disk. typo

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(physics)

Comment: This question should be reopened - for a hypothetical static observer hovering near the horizon, the Hawking radiation may indeed appear hotter than the Sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat in black holes is due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_temperature), which means in particular that the temperature you measure will depend on the observer you are considering. For an observer at infinity, the temperature is given by the Hawking temperature,
$$T_H = \frac{\hbar c^3}{8\pi k_B G M}.$$
Or, in units with $\hbar = c = G = k_B = 1$,
$$T_H = \frac{1}{8\pi M}.$$
However, *this is the temperature measured by static observers at infinity*. In other words, it is the temperature that observers at a fixed, infinite "radial distance" to the center of the black hole measure. Other observers measure other temperatures. If you are free falling, you won't measure any temperature at all: it is $T = 0 \text{K}$. If you are at a fixed, finite radial distance $r$, then the temperature is
$$T_H = \frac{1}{8\pi M \sqrt{1 - \frac{2 M}{r}}}.$$
Notice that $r \to +\infty$ recovers the previous formula. Furthermore, for $r \to 2M$ (i.e., close to the horizon), the temperature gets arbitrarily large. Hence, yes, the black hole will be hotter than the Sun if you are hovering sufficiently close to it. Furthermore, there is no limit on the black hole's mass: this will be true for a black hole of any size, as long as you are close enough.

Notice an important point: the temperature depends on the observer measuring it. A free falling observer will be freezing with the cold, but a hovering observer will be burning with the heat.

As for a more detailed comparison on heat spectrum, black holes are black bodies (okay, [there are some caveats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_greybody_factors)), while the Sun is not, and its emission is altered by its composition.

Comment: Do solar systems exist that orbit a black hole instead of a sun, whereby the black hole is a source of any possible life on its surrounding planets?

Comment: @user610620 I'm not sure, but I find that very unlikely. From a planetary distance, the temperature would be very low.

Comment: But the answer describes how a black hole can be warmer than a sun. Wouldn't that mean at planetary distance, the black hole could be life-giving.

Comment: @user610620 No. Notice that I said "the black hole will be hotter than the Sun **if you are hovering sufficiently close to it**". Sufficiently close, in these scenarios, is way closer than planetary distance.

Comment: Swap in white hole for black hole. Can the planet now contain life due to energy from the white hole?

Comment: @user610620 I don't know much about white holes, so I'm not sure. In fact, I'm not even sure if it makes sense to talk about such a situation. I think a white hole might be unstable, unless in the particular case of an eternal black hole (which also has a white hole region). That might deserve a new post. Anyway, I don't know whether there is any reason to believe white holes are physical.